# Adding an R2R Digital to analog converter inline with TRS connector

Tags: circuits, circuit-design, audio-engineering

I am trying to create a simple R2R DAC, maybe 8-16 bits.

I want to be able to that type of DAC inline to a headphone line.

Since the an 8 bit R2R DAC will need 8 pins, how exactly do I wire up a TRS connector to that?

Do I have to put an analog to digital converter inline first?

3.5mm TRS analog audio player output ->
[create analog to digital output] ->
[apply the digital signal to my 8bit DAC] ->
output to 3.5mm TRS analog

[image]

Comment: The electrical stack may be a better place for your question , also people on here choose what they reply to and there is no minimum response time : have patience , a person who could reply may be in a different time zone and sleeping , eating or enjoying life...

Comment: There is too much hand waving to understand what you are really trying to do.  Closing as *unclear*.  Also, have you even thought about the error budget for just a 8 bit D/A, let alone 16 bit?

Comment: I just noticed you answered your own question.  I haven't read it, but apparently we're done here anyway.

Comment: Your question can match better the topic of https://electronics.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I will go ahead and answer my own question.

Since I'll have to deal with an analog signal anyways, coming from the audio output of a mobile device.

I'll need an ADC [analog to digital converter]
then I'll match that up with a DAC [digital to analog converter]
and send that out a TRS plug.

This thing will need it's own power supply for it all but I think it might be a fun project to do.

[enter link description here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-13/digital-analog-conversion/)